# How to change data type to double from a Variable in PHP

Tags: php

I got a Variable $a as result from calculation from equations.

```
$a = 2.367760572051E-5
```

I need an output so the result of $a is 0.00002367760572051
So I try to convert the variable to double using this :

```
$result = (double)$a;
```

But the result is still the same,. 
Is there any way to convert it?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.doubleval.php

Comment: PHP doesn't have variable types like C or Java. Your question is nonexistent: you're asking how to format a string representation of a number

Comment: Try this: `$result = $a + 0;`

Comment: you want to use `sprintf` or `number_format`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you're after is a formatted string, try this one out

```
$result = sprintf('%0.17f', $a);
```

There's also

```
$result = number_format($a, 17);
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want a result to print, try this.

```
$str = sprintf("%.20f",$a);
echo $str;
```

then you can result belows as.

```
 0.00002367760572051
```

Comment: This does not always give the expected results, mind the locale.

Comment: sorry, it's fixed. it's a typo. %.0f -> %.20f
i checked on runtime. it works.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is dynamically typed. Your variable `$a` is already a `double` internally. No need to typecast it again.

Use function [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to format the `double` as desired.